# HighCharts: Possible to summarize series data and show in title?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm looking for an answer if it's possible to sum the HighCharts series and show it in the title? I'm using JSON data for the series, so if the data looks like this:

```
[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

The sum should of course be: 18.

I've tried asking Google but I haven't found anything. I know I could handle it elsewhere but it would be nice to handle it directly inside the HighCharts script.

Thx.

/CRH

Comment: I forgot to mention that the JSON data is loaded from an external PHP file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about summing it in Javascript and then using the result when creating the title?

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i in series)
    sum += i;
```

Then, just set the title:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    ...

    title: {
        text: 'SUM: ' + sum
    },

    ...
)};
```

That should work, right?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the JSON data is loaded from an external PHP file. Can I use your method anyway?

Comment: The same idea should definitely work. The main idea is just to compute a sum and then put it in the title somewhere. You can do that in JavaScript (as I've shown) or with PHP or whatever you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Because you pass an object literal to Highcharts, you best bet might be to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/WRa43/

```
var data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

$('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
        data: data
    }],

    title: {
        text: "Total is " + data.reduce(function(i,a) { return i+a; })
    }
});
```

Reference for [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: I like that `reduce` call. I didn't know that existed.