# Display the total count of json key-value pairs in the series in high charts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have a json array whic has a key status and two value pass and rescan. I need to display the percentage of pass and rescan based on their total counts in highcharts. Currently I have given the hard coded values as 2 and 1 in the series section of the code.

Below is my highcharts code:

```
    $(function () {

    // Make monochrome colors and set them as default for all pies
    Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors = (function () {
        var colors = [],
            base = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
            // Start out with a darkened base color (negative brighten), and end
            // up with a much brighter color
            colors.push(Highcharts.Color(base).brighten((i - 3) / 7).get());
        }
        return colors;
    }());

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Authentic vs. Rescan, 2016'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Status',
            data: [
                { name: 'Authentic', y: 2 },
                { name: 'Rescan', y: 1 }
            ]
        }]
    });
});

 /*chart theme*/
/**
 * Dark theme for Highcharts JS
 * @author Torstein Honsi
 */

Highcharts.createElement('link', {
   href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One',
   rel: 'stylesheet',
   type: 'text/css'
}, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);

Highcharts.theme = {
   colors: ["#27ecea", "#90ee7e", "#f45b5b", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
      "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
   chart: {
      backgroundColor: {
          linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
         stops: [
            [0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'],
            [1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)']
            ]

      },
      style: {
         fontFamily: "'Unica One', sans-serif"
      },
      plotBorderColor: '#606063'
   },
   title: {
      style: {
         color: '#E0E0E3',
         textTransform: 'uppercase',
         fontSize: '20px'
      }
   },
   subtitle: {
      style: {
         color: '#E0E0E3',
         textTransform: 'uppercase'
      }
   },
   xAxis: {
      gridLineColor: '#707073',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#E0E0E3'
         }
      },
      lineColor: '#707073',
      minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
      tickColor: '#707073',
      title: {
         style: {
            color: '#A0A0A3'

         }
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
      gridLineColor: '#707073',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#E0E0E3'
         }
      },
      lineColor: '#707073',
      minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
      tickColor: '#707073',
      tickWidth: 1,
      title: {
         style: {
            color: '#A0A0A3'
         }
      }
   },
   tooltip: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
      style: {
         color: '#F0F0F0'
      }
   },
   plotOptions: {
      series: {
         dataLabels: {
            color: '#B0B0B3'
         },
         marker: {
            lineColor: '#333'
         }
      },
      boxplot: {
         fillColor: '#505053'
      },
      candlestick: {
         lineColor: 'white'
      },
      errorbar: {
         color: 'white'
      }
   },
   legend: {
      itemStyle: {
         color: '#E0E0E3'
      },
      itemHoverStyle: {
         color: '#FFF'
      },
      itemHiddenStyle: {
         color: '#606063'
      }
   },
   credits: {
      style: {
         color: '#666'
      }
   },
   labels: {
      style: {
         color: '#707073'
      }
   },

   drilldown: {
      activeAxisLabelStyle: {
         color: '#F0F0F3'
      },
      activeDataLabelStyle: {
         color: '#F0F0F3'
      }
   },

   navigation: {
      buttonOptions: {
         symbolStroke: '#DDDDDD',
         theme: {
            fill: '#505053'
         }
      }
   },


   rangeSelector: {
      buttonTheme: {
         fill: '#505053',
         stroke: '#000000',
         style: {
            color: '#CCC'
         },
         states: {
            hover: {
               fill: '#707073',
               stroke: '#000000',
               style: {
                  color: 'white'
               }
            },
            select: {
               fill: '#000003',
               stroke: '#000000',
               style: {
                  color: 'white'
               }
            }
         }
      },
      inputBoxBorderColor: '#505053',
      inputStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#333',
         color: 'silver'
      },
      labelStyle: {
         color: 'silver'
      }
   },

   navigator: {
      handles: {
         backgroundColor: '#666',
         borderColor: '#AAA'
      },
      outlineColor: '#CCC',
      maskFill: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
      series: {
         color: '#7798BF',
         lineColor: '#A6C7ED'
      },
      xAxis: {
         gridLineColor: '#505053'
      }
   },

   scrollbar: {
      barBackgroundColor: '#808083',
      barBorderColor: '#808083',
      buttonArrowColor: '#CCC',
      buttonBackgroundColor: '#606063',
      buttonBorderColor: '#606063',
      rifleColor: '#FFF',
      trackBackgroundColor: '#404043',
      trackBorderColor: '#404043'
   },


   legendBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
   background2: '#505053',
   dataLabelsColor: '#B0B0B3',
   textColor: '#C0C0C0',
   contrastTextColor: '#F0F0F3',
   maskColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'
};

Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
/*---------------*/
```

Below is my json:

```
    var json={
    "BMS": [{
        "id":"A",
        "fname": "vid123431.mp4",
        "lat": "73.81303019",
        "lng": "18.58494347",
        "status": "pass"
    },{
        "id":"B",
        "fname": "vid123431.mp4",
        "lat": "23.986",
        "lng": "32.345645",
        "status": "pass"
    }, {
        "id":"C",
        "fname": "VID_20160801_154039509.mp4",
        "lat": "23.986",
        "lng": "32.345645",
        "date": "2016-08-01",
        "time": "15:41:37",
        "status": "rescan"
    }
]
}
```

Could any one help on this?

Comment: Possibly the duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335366/highcharts-possible-to-summarize-series-data-and-show-in-title

Comment: Actually in that link it is related to summing just all the integer values and displaying. In my case I need to count number of resacan status and number of pass status. Based on that count I need to display bar chart.

Comment: This example might help: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/mxpwrh34/ can't find the original question at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over your JSON data and count the number of pass and rescan:

```
 Highcharts.each(json.BMS, function(p) {
   if (p.status === 'pass') {
     passNumber++;
   } else if (p.status === 'rescan') {
     rescanNumber++;
   }
 });
```

Then you can make series containing information about counts of pass and rescan:

```
 var series = {
   name: 'Status',
   data: [{
     name: 'pass',
     y: passNumber
   }, {
     name: 'rescan',
     y: rescanNumber
   }]
 };
```

Here you can find an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/worg6jLz/42/